# Jenkins build notification affecting all branches in bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment

I have previously use Jenkins and BitBucket on premises and been able to have Jenkins notify bitbucket of the build condition of each individual branch (success, failed, in progress) however since I moved to bitbucket cloud it has started applying the condition of every build on every branch to every branch. For example if I have just a master and develop branch (to keep it simple) and the master branch failed because of some deployment configuration I am unable to merge a fix into it from develop even if develop is passing because it claims 1 of my 2 builds is failing on the develop branch.

This is tough to explain clearly in words so I've attached some pictures:

[image: Two branches one build failing but both being marked as failed]
Two branches one build failing but both being marked as failed

[image: Showing that develop branch is passing]
Showing that develop branch is passing

[image: Proof it wont let me merge]
Proof it wont let me merge

These notifications come from jenkins and have been set up using the standard cloudbees-bitbucket-branch-source:2.9.7 plugin to scan my bit bucket cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this was a really obvious mistake but I thought I would leave the reason why this happened here in case any one makes the same mistake. cloudbees-bitbucket-branch-source:2.9.7 notifies bitbucket using the commit ID, when creating the branch structure for the repository I branched off main to make develop and both got built but both had the same commit ID and so both were notified of both builds. The problem fixes it's self on the first cycle of code to run through it.